# Can a low-level caster attempt to use a Spell Scroll of a spell that isn't on his class's spell list but is on his subclass's list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, class-feature, archetype

A caster can attempt to use a [spell scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) of a spell he can't normally cast  (DC of 10 + Spell level) if said spell is on his spell list.

Some subclasses give access, at certain levels, to spells that aren't on the main class's list. For example, the War Domain of the Cleric class gives, at 5th level, access to the normally Paladin-exclusive *crusader's mantle* spell.

**Can a low-level caster attempt to use a spell scroll of a spell that isn't on his class's general spell list, but is on his subclass's added list?** For example, Bob the level 1 War Cleric attempting to use a scroll of *crusader's mantle*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No, you have to wait until the indicated level to cast them

Sub-class spells won't be added to the class list for you until you actually gain the feature that adds them.

It depends on how exactly the feature is worded (so different classes will differ), but for [cleric domains](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#DivineDomain) it says:

> Each domain has a list of spells - its domain spells - that **you gain at the cleric levels noted** in the domain description. Once you gain a domain spell, you always have it prepared, and it doesn't count against the number of spells you can prepare each day.
>
> If you have a domain spell that doesn't appear on the cleric spell list, the spell is nonetheless a cleric spell for you.

Until you hit the level indicated in the Domain Spells table, you don't have the associated domain spell. In this case, you need to be a 5th level War cleric to gain *crusader's mantle* as a domain spell, which in turn allows you to use scrolls of it since it is now a cleric spell (ie. on the cleric spell list) for you.